# ¿como usar correctamente header location de php?

Tags: php

tengo una pagina web , cuando hay un id guardado en una sesion, se debe redirigir a la pagina de index.php seccion home y salir del formulario de login, pero el header location no funciona en mi caso, ya probe eliminanado comentarios , espacios en blanco y cualquier impresion por pantalla y no funciona, no hace nada, quisiera saber si me podrian ayudar, gracias.

```
<?php
 if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  header("Location:http://localhost/veterinaria/index.php");
     echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
     $_GET['seccion'] == 'home';
   }
?>
```

esta es la url desde donde quiero redirigir, y se aplica el header en esa pagina y no hace nada, se queda ahi.
http://localhost/veterinaria/index.php?seccion=login

Comment: ¿Esas líneas de código son lo primero que tenes en el archivo? ¿No veo que tengas `session_start` por lo que deberías obtener un _Notice_ indicando que `$_SESSION['user_id']` no esta definida. PD: Después de un `header` de redirección lo recomendable poner un `die();` para evitar que se continue el proceso.

Comment: las lineas de codigo las tiene el archivo login.php el cual esta incluido  en el index.php, alli, esta session_start()

Comment: Al parecer la condición no se está cumpliendo, depura tu código, poniendo por ejemplo `var_dump($_SESSION['user_id']);` o bien `var_dump($_SESSION);`. Por otra parte, no tiene sentido poner cosas **después de location**. Si quieres pasar datos debes ponerlos en la URL o en la variable de sesión.

Comment: si cumple porque imprime por pantalla la session,

Comment: ademas, solo  deje el header en el condicional quitando la impresion de la session y el GET, y tampoco funciona, se queda ahi mismo

Comment: Pues muy raro. ¿Qué pasa si pones esto en el navegador directamente: `http://localhost/veterinaria/index.php`?

Comment: Puedes poner todo el código para revisarlo en mi ambiente??